# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): data.filter is not a function - D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I am trying to build a line chart in D3 (version 5) and I get the following error:

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): data.filter is not a function
```

I'm not sure why I am getting this as I have used this boilerplate code before.

Here is my code:

```
const LineGraph = (props) => {

var margin = {top: 80, right: 80, bottom: 80, left: 80},
width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("#svgLineChart").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var lineData = svg.append("g"); 

lineData.selectAll(".lineData")
            .data(lineData)
            .enter()
            .append('lineData')
            .attr('class', 'lineData')
            .attr('id', function(d) { return d.casino, d.table_and_other, d.poker, \
             d.slot_machines, d.total_gaming_win, d.combined_date});

var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]); 
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]); 
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom().scale(x).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat('%b %Y'));
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft().scale(y).ticks(4);

var line = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) { return x(d.combined_date); })
  .y(function(d) { return y(d.table_and_other); })

var lineTwo = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) { return x(d.combined_date); })
  .y(function(d) { return y(d.poker); });

var lineThree = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) { return x(d.combined_date); })
  .y(function(d) { return y(d.slot_machines); });

var lineFour = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) { return x(d.combined_date); })
  .y(function(d) { return y(d.total_gaming_win); });

function type(d) {
   d.casino = d.casino;
   d.table_and_other = +d.table_and_other;
   d.poker = +d.poker;
   d.slot_machines = +d.slot_machines;
   d.total_gaming_win = +d.total_gaming_win;
   d.combined_date =d.combined_date;
   //d.combined_date = parse(d.combined_date);
   return d;
 };

var data = d3.csv("./total_cleaned_up.csv", type, function(error, data) {
console.log(data);
```

Here is where the error occurs:

```
var ballys = data.filter(function(d) {
  return d.casino == "Ballys";
});
```

For some reason the filter function isn't working properly ...
code resumes down below

```
x.domain([ballys[0].combined_date, ballys[ballys.length - 1].combined_date]);
y.domain([0, d3.max(hardRock, function(d) { return d.total_gaming_win; })]).nice();


 // Add the clip path.
 svg.append("clipPath")
  .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

 // Add the x-axis.
 svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

 // Add the y-axis.
  svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + width + ",0)")
  .call(yAxis);

})

}
```

Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: I guess your "data" is not an array.

Comment: Could you add a console.log(JSON.stringify(data)) right before the line that causes the error? My guess is that the data isn't loaded yet and we need to wait for it

Comment: @davidgamero i added the line and don't see anything logged into the console